The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain:Untrust
Here is info about our technical development environment :
.NET 6
C# 10
Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996
Visual Studio 2022
Windows 10 Enterprise
Here is the content of the Dockerfile that is associated with our Visual Studio 2022 solution:
Docker File:
Docker File
nuget.config file:
nuget.config
When i am trying to create the docker image receiving the following SSL error. Could please any one help here who already experienced if the similar type of issue
Error log
all the details have been mentioned above

Welcome to SO. Please read this and edit your question so the text is included in your post instead of the screenshots.
